# docker Unix syslog delivery error

Tags: docker, syslog, rsyslog

I faced at syslog related error when executing the program with the docker.

```
docker run -d -e SERVER_ADDR=127.0.0.1 --name go-agent1 go-agent:1.0
```

> **Docker logs:** 2019/03/15 01:59:08 Unix syslog delivery error

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN mkdir -p /cloud/config

WORKDIR /cloud

COPY go_agent go_agent (==>go_agent is go lang program)
COPY config/agent.conf config/agent.conf
COPY cloud-settings cloud-settings

CMD ["sh","-c","/cloud/cloud-settings ; /cloud/go_agent"]
#CMD ["/cloud/go_agent"] ==> Running go_agent alone will work.
```

When I run go_agent alone, it works fine.
but after cloud-settings shell, go_agent cause syslog delivery error.

**cloud-settings**

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 234 90 90

sed -i '3i\  "agent_server_ip":"'${SERVER_ADDR}'",' config/agent.conf
```

I want to know how to fix syslog error.

Comment: Can you please verify if the syslog is running - $ ps -aux | grep syslog

Comment: there are no syslog.
how to set it?? I install rsyslog.

Comment: yes, please install the syslog. That's why you are getting the error. Once the syslog is up, the error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

try commenting this line in /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
#$OmitLocalLogging on
```